# Has there been an attempt to create a classification system or taxonomy of "everything"

Tags: ontology, terminology, classification

I have only begun digging into the philosophical definitions and study of taxonomy/classification, however I am just wondering if thus far the idea of trying to categorize and classify all objects, concepts et cetera into a class/sub-class hierarchy has been attempted or discussed? What fields of study would this fall under? I assume philosophy but also some other branches of academia?

Comment: Such global taxonomies are called [architectonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectonics). Aristotle, Kant and Peirce attempted three historically prominent versions. It fell out of favor after that as hopeless.

Comment: Inventors of "universal" or "perfect" languages often rely on such classifications and also self-styled encyclopaedists: Umberto Eco in various works has reported many instances.